# How can I click Quarterly button on Yahoo financials and get Quarterly data instead of Annual data?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, browser-automation

I want to navigate to https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT and click the quarterly button [image]

This is my code so far:

```
def clickQuarterlyButton(url):
    try:
        options = Options()
        #options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = 
       webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, constants.SLEEP_TIME).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close']"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, constants.SLEEP_TIME).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[1]/div[2]/button'))).click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        #print(soup)
        return soup 
    except Exception as e:
        print('-------------------------------------------------')
        print('EXCEPTION OCCURED IN CLICK QUARTERLY BUTTON !!!!')
        print(e)
        print('-------------------------------------------------')
        return None
```

When I check what `soup` returns, it still only shows annual data and not quarterly data. Another interesting note I see when I run this script without `--headless` is that the `Markets` tab gets clicked as shown in screenshot below and the quarterly button does not get clicked but not sure why that would even happen:
[image]

Anyone know how I can grab the quarterly data by clicking on the Quarterly button and returning quarterly data?

Comment: you should consider using API to access data, there is a python library for that [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)

Comment: Anyway, did you try adding `time.sleep(3)` before `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')`? Because when you click on Quarterly, it takes 1-2 seconds to load the new data, so you have to wait a bit before getting the soup